# What is the difference between function as method and function as property?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, visual-studio-code, properties

The function in JavaScript object are recognized as methods or properties depending by code.

What is the difference? Maybe a vscode bug?

I couldn't figure it out, so please tell me why.

[image: example 01]

[image: example 02]

Comment: Can you give more context? A *method* in JavaScript is typically a function assigned to an instance.

Comment: https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/property-vs-method/456866/3

Comment: The function object create via a method definition is slightly different. E.g. it is not constructable, i.e you cannot use it with `new`.